# nodejs Stripe, retrieveUpcoming and upgrading subscription

Tags: node.js, stripe-payments, payment

I am a bit stuck so I'm turning to you.

I have a system of subscriptions. The customer can only upgrade his subscription.

So the idea is that you have the different plans we offer, let's say you have account: silver (30$) gold (90$)  and platinium(180$)

if the user has a free account, it's a regular subscription creation.

So the scenario is the following:

My customer goest from free to silver.

After a weeks he realize gold is fitting to his needs so he upgrades he has a preview of his next invoice and this works no problem so far with the following function:

```
await stripe.invoices.retrieveUpcoming({
  customer: this.body('customer'),
  subscription: this.body('sub'),
  subscription_plan: this.body('newPlan'),
});
```

so the problem arise when the customer wants to upgrade again.  Using the subscription_plan parameters bugs, and prevent the upgrade from being done.

How can i do that ? Do i need to create a new subscription ? What am i doing wrong

Using subscription_items seemed to do the job, the the invoice is giving me hell to fetch the data correctly with the prorata.

Answer (score 1):

You can [upgrade (or downgrade) a subscription](https://stripe.com/docs/billing/subscriptions/upgrade-downgrade) by calling `stripe.subscriptions.update`.

Notably this will take care of any prorations for you, and you can specify your preferred proration behaviour when [updating](https://stripe.com/docs/api/subscriptions/update#update_subscription-proration_behavior). You can learn more about how Stripe handles prorations [here](https://stripe.com/docs/billing/subscriptions/prorations).

Comment: Thanks, that's already what i'm doing, but I need to preview the invoice and that's where i get most problems

Comment: @Reyem Why are you passing a `subscription_plan` parameter? There's no such parameter on the [retrieve upcoming invoice API](https://stripe.com/docs/api/invoices/upcoming). You can just pass the subscription ID and if the update call was successful, the updated invoice will be returned.